# Calling Httpget() in Multiviews/Nested states of UIRouter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, http-get

Iam new to AngularJS and now facing an issue with uirouter multiple views. Searched for various examples,but couldn’t find a solution. Hope you will help.
I have a submit function inside controller in nested view. When a user clicks on submit, the subt_click() has to be invoked and an url has to be created based on the date provided and should call data from that url and display in a table.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">   
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-5">
                <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" ng-model="dates.date3" is-open="ctrl.open.date3" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.openCalendar($event, 'date3')"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</form>
<a ui-sref=".submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="subt_click()">Submit</a>
</div>
```

Below is how I have declared states and called the subt_click().

app.js:

```
var wc = angular.module('wc', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker']);
wc.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/posts');
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {            
        url: '/tab1',
        templateUrl: 'tab.html'
    })        
     .state('tab.submit', {               
            url: '/submit',
            templateUrl: 'tab-submit.html',
            //controller: 'MyController'
        }) 

    .state('tabs', {
        url: '/tabs',
        templateUrl: 'tabs.html',         
    });
});
wc.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $filter) {
var that = this;
var in10Days = new Date();
in10Days.setDate(in10Days.getDate() + 10);
$scope.dates = {
    date3: " ",
    date4: " "
};
this.dates = {
    date3: new Date(),
    date4: new Date(),
};
this.open = {
    date3: false,
    date4: false,
};
// Disable weekend selection
this.disabled = function (date, mode) {
    return (mode === 'day' && (new Date().toDateString() == date.toDateString()));
};
this.dateOptions = {
    showWeeks: false,
    startingDay: 1
};
this.timeOptions = {
    readonlyInput: false,
    showMeridian: false
};
this.dateModeOptions = {
    minMode: 'year',
    maxMode: 'year'
};
this.openCalendar = function (e, date) {
    that.open[date] = true;
};

$scope.format = 'yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm';
debugger;
$scope.subt_click = function () {
    var date = $filter("date")($scope.dates.date3, $scope.format);     
            $http.get("URLpartA"+date+"URLpartB")
        .success( function(response) {
            debugger
            $scope.condition = response.Table
            console.log(response)
        });      
};
});
```

tab-submit.html:

```
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in condition">
                <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Name}}</td>                    
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is a plunk to check the code: `plunker`:http://plnkr.co/edit/3Iyao5aOt2tY7Ze104dp?p=preview.

the displayed table is empty and not the data from url(URL am using is from local host).There are no errors on console and from console.log(response) I could see the array objects from url.

Am not sure where this has went wrong. Will be really grateful if anyone can help!!

Comment: I tried your plunk and had two console errors. `Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object` and the get request returned 400 bad request. Assuming your local code works, what is the value of `response` in your success callback?

Comment: @Haymaker87: {"Table":[{"ID":6,"Name":"Jack"},{"ID:7","Name":"Jill"}]}

Comment: Okay, in that case I will have to assume your controllers aren't mapped properly to that view. What happens if you uncomment `//controller: "MyController"` in your routes block?

Comment: @Haymaker87: No change its same

Comment: I am not sure why you are adding `$location.path('/date');` in the controller. Explain that. It might happen that the `$location` change happens before your `http get` call completes.

Comment: @Venkat: As you said I don't need it here, updated my question and plunker.

Comment: You have a `div` with `ng-controller` set and you have a `ui-view` outside of this `div`. Now, on a state change, the `ui-view` refreshes and it has no clue about the controller of the `div`. Hence, a new instance of the controller is created - this controller has the variable `condition` as `null`. Hence, your table has no rows. You'd ideally want to put the data into a service and inject that service into `MyController` which should allow you to share data between the 2 views or you can pass the data through `resolve`.

Comment: @Venkat: Here is how i have added resolve http://plnkr.co/edit/nPGGndGCwX3CIuwdB6gI?p=preview, which is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tbIhYZFHDVUO7Jm4PhqH). I've added a controller, a dummy service to fetch data and used the service in `resolve` to inject data into the controller.

Comment: This plunker has way too many issues for to resolve. That is why I did a new one.

Comment: But that is the code where I need to workon. Couldn't sortit